# how i can view what is covered inside the "abstract class Controller" for Dispose method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a new asp.net mvc-5 web application using Visual Studio 2013. and I mapped my database tables using entity framework 6,which generated a `.edmx` file. then I chose to create a new Controller class . I checked the generated code for the new controller class and I find that at the end of the controller class I got the following for disposing the current http request:-

```
 protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

now i know the following facts about Disposing the current http request:-

1. the above Dispose() method will override the Dispose method inside Controller base class. and this Dispose method will be called at the end of http request handling.
2. the above Dispose() method will dispose the current db connection , then call the Dispose() method inside the Controller base class.

but I have the following questions:-

1. when I tried accessing the base dispose method, using "go to definition", as follow:-

[image]

i was redirected inside the abstract class, with empty method implementation for `Dispose()`.so is there a way to know the implementation for the dispose method inside the Controller base class?

2. on some online tutorials they call the following method inside the dispose method:-

   GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

so i am not sure if this is part of the default implementation for the `Dispose()` method inside the Controller base class , or i need to explicitly call the garbage collectors inside the Dispose method ?

Thanks

**Edit**
here is the public abstract class Controller code where the dispose method is empty:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should read this [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) article on Microsoft, it goes through all of the recommendations as well as Does and Donts.

> ... .so is there a way to know the implementation for the dispose method inside the Controller base class?

The MVC `Controller` type does not have an actual implementation for `Dispose` but does offer a placeholder for your code in the form of a virtual method that you can override.

```
/// <summary>
/// Releases all resources that are used by the current instance of the <see cref="T:System.Web.Mvc.Controller"/> class.
/// </summary>
public void Dispose()
{
  this.Dispose(true);
  GC.SuppressFinalize((object) this);
}

/// <summary>
/// Releases unmanaged resources and optionally releases managed resources.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="disposing">true to release both managed and unmanaged resources; false to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
}
```

> .. on some online tutorials they call the following method inside the dispose method: `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`. so i am not sure if this is part of the default implementation for the Dispose()...

No, you should only have to call this if you are actually working with unmanaged code / memory directly in which case you should implement a finalizer or use a safehandle on your type to ensure that the unmanaged memory is released. Also see the Microsoft documentation on [GC.SuppressFinalize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize(v=vs.110).aspx). In the case of the MVC `Controller` type it is already called for you so no need to add it again.

The call to `GC.SuppressFinalize` makes sure that if a type has a finalizer and is Disposable (implements IDisposable) that it is not promoted to the next generation in the Garbage Collector which makes it stick around for a while longer after which the finalizer will get called when that generation of objects is released. It tells the Garbage Collector that the object has already been cleaned up and the finalizer does not need to run so go ahead and release/free all the memory associated with this object. Again, if you do not have a finalizer on the object this is not necessary as GC should not promote the object to the next generation when running.

Comment: @lgor so you mean currently my Controller base class does not have any implementation for the Dispose() method ? so currently calling the base.Dispose(disposing ) inside my controller is meangless ?

Comment: @JohnJohn - It does have an implementation that then calls back to the virtual protected method `Dispose(bool disposing)` which you can then implement in your code. Ill add that method as well in my answer (2 seconds).

Comment: @lgor so the code show in this link for the base controller class http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs is not there inside any new project ?strange ? i though the code in this link will be already inside the base controller class ?

Comment: So anything you want to dispose you should do in an override of that virtual method. Check the boolean flag through and only do it when that flag is true. If it is false the finalizer is running and chances are your managed references are no longer valid.

Comment: @lgor so the code show in this link for the base controller class aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/… is not there inside any new project ?strange ? i though the code in this link will be already inside the base controller class ?

Comment: @JohnJohn - it is inside the base controller class. What I have above is exactly the same as the link you just sent. Maybe you are using an old(er) version of MVC??

Comment: I am using visual studio 2013 + mvc 5 web application.. now my "public abstract class Controller" does not provide any implementations for the methods, it only contain the methods definition. I edit my question with a screen shot of how my "public abstract class Controller " looks like..thanks

Comment: @JohnJohn - that must be the definition showing you the implementation incorrectly or just showing the method signatures. I am sure of this because any method in an abstract class must define a body / implementation unless it is also marked as abstract which those are not. In your own Controller implementation you should be able to create an override for the `void Dispose(boolean)` method but not for the `void Dispose()` method.

Comment: @lgor so how I can see this controller code http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs inside visual studio ? seems currently VS will be showing the metadata only without the actual implementation.. so how I can view the actual implementation inside the visual studio ? did you get my question? now I find this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms236403.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 which talk about this ,, but they did not mention how I can view the actual implementation ...

Comment: @JohnJohn - install [JetBrain's DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). IMO its better than the built in VS Go To Def. That should allow you to view the actual implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [the code for Controller](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs) and search for the Dispose method which is just this:

```
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true /* disposing */);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
```

Comment: so why this code is not shown inside visual studio ? do I need to provide this code inside my current project ? now current the System.Web.Mvc.Controller class is inside the following location "C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\14384$System.Web.Mvc.dll$v4.0.30319$NoDynamic" but its methods are empty..

Comment: so the code for the controller class inside the link you  provide will not be there by default inside any new asp.net mvc projects ?

Comment: can you advice on this please?